# How to solve the python request get and C# HttpClient get to get the data is not the same

Tags: python, c#, web-crawler

I want to change my Python project to use C#, and now I have a problem.
I used the same headers to get JSON data from same url, but the data I get is different.
C# get the json data is incomplete.

```
// This is a C# code snippet

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
HttpResponseMessage response;

Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
   {"user-agent" , MY_UA},
   {"accept-encoding" , "gzip, deflate" },
   {"accept" , "application/json" },
   {"connection" , "keep-alive" },
   {"referer" , REFERER },
   {"cookie" , COOKIE }
};

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in headers)
{
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
}

try
{
   response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
   throw new Exception("Failed to make the request. " + ex.Message);
}

if ((int)response.StatusCode == 200)
{
   return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

```
# This is python code
headers = {
    "user-agent": MY_UA,
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "referer": REFERER,
    "cookie": COOKIE,
}
response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
```

I tried to capture the packets using Wireshark and found that the packet length of the sending request header is different. And the last packet in C# shows an error.
And of course UA and referer and cookie are exactly the same.

```
This is C# packets
Protocol  Length  Info
TCP         66     6224  >  443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM
TCP         66     443  >  6224 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1400 SACK_PERM WS=8192
TCP         54     6224  >  443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=263168 Len=0
TLSv1.3     318    Client Hello
TCP         60     443  >  6224 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=265 Win=57344 Len=0
TLSv1.3     1514   Server Hello, Change Cipher Spec
TLSv1.3     1202   Application Data
TCP         54     6224  >  443 [ACK] Seq=265 Ack=2609 Win=263168 Len=0
TLSv1.3     463    Change Cipher Spec, Application Data, Application Data
TCP         60     443  >  6224 [ACK] Seq=2609 Ack=674 Win=65536 Len=0
TLSv1.3     1514   Application Data
TLSv1.3     483    Application Data
TCP         54     6224  >  443 [ACK] Seq=674 Ack=4498 Win=263168 Len=0
TLSv1.3     675    Application Data

TCP         54     6224  >  443 [RST, ACK] Seq=674 Ack=5119 Win=0 Len=0
            ↑ This is the error packet
```

```
This is python packets
Protocol  Length  Info
TCP         66     6187  >  443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM
TCP         66     443  >  6187 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1400 SACK_PERM WS=8192
TCP         54     6187  >  443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=263168 Len=0
TLSv1.3     571    Client Hello
TCP         60     443  >  6187 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=518 Win=57344 Len=0
TLSv1.3     1514   Server Hello, Change Cipher Spec
TLSv1.3     1217   Application Data
TCP         54     6187  >  443 [ACK] Seq=518 Ack=2624 Win=263168 Len=0
TLSv1.3     134    Change Cipher Spec, Application Data
TCP         1454   6187  >  443 [ACK] Seq=598 Ack=2624 Win=263168 Len=1400 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
TLSv1.3     304    Application Data
TCP         60     443  >  6187 [ACK] Seq=2624 Ack=2248 Win=57344 Len=0
TLSv1.3     1514   Application Data
TLSv1.3     483    Application Data
TCP         54     6187  >  443 [ACK] Seq=2248 Ack=4513 Win=263168 Len=0
TLSv1.3     1330   Application Data
TCP         54     6187  >  443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=2248 Ack=5789 Win=261888 Len=0
TCP         60     443  >  6187 [FIN, ACK] Seq=5789 Ack=2249 Win=65536 Len=0
TCP         54     6187  >  443 [ACK] Seq=2249 Ack=5790 Win=261888 Len=0
```

Comment: Why are then packets important here? Why not use a tool like Telerik's Fiddler that actually shows you the request at the application layer level? It's far more useful than Wireshark for diagnosing problems with HTTP requests. Also, you might want to look at using properties like `UserAgent` rather than adding headers as you are.